# postgresql dblink pgpass.conf could not establish connection

Tags: windows, postgresql, connection, dblink

- I have a PostgreSQL x64 10 installation on windows 2012 server running on port 5433

  - I try to use the dblink from within the database to the same database.
  - I don't want to set the password in the dblink command.
  - I want to use the pgpass.conf file for the password.
  - PostgreSQL is installed with Administrator account.
  - PostgreSQL service is ran by system local account.
  - I have set the pgpass.conf file in the %APPADATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf as follow: "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Roaming\PostgreSQL\pgpass.conf"

    `localhost:5433:*:postgres:pwd
    127.0.0.1:5433:*:postgres:pwd
    localhost:5433:*:adm:pwd
    127.0.0.1:5433:*:adm:pwd`

when I connect to PostgreSQL with `psql -U adm -d HST` no password is required
but when I use the dblink as follow:

`HST=# select * FROM dblink('port=5433 dbname=HST user=adm host=localhost', 'select hd from sys_erreur') AS p (ret timestamp);
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DÉTAIL : fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Has someone already experienced this and found any solution?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately for dblink you have to add password into connection string.

Comment: thanks for the answer :(